Getting Execution timeout Expired from Hangfire RecurringJobSchedular
I am running multiple instances of application. I am inserting about 30M data in different table. After my jobs complete it goes into processing state. During that time I am getting error like Execution Timeout Expired. Looking at the stack trace errors  seems to be in SqlServerDistributedLock.cs line 12.
RecurringJobSchedular does recover automatically.
